# Facebook SDK Login URL Exposing the Client Secret?

Tags: facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

I'm currently building a website where I'll offer the users a link to share a photo on Facebook, whereby the application would:

- Provide the user with a link to request permissions from Facebook
- Redirect back to the website with the access code from the user's acceptance of the permissions
- Server-side post the photo to the user's photos

To generate the link for the first step, I'm doing this:

```
var fb = new FacebookClient();
var options = new
{
    client_id = "MY_APP_ID",
    client_secret = "MY_APP_SECRET",
    redirect_uri = string.Format("http://localhost:51182/Home/FacebookShare?path={0}", Server.UrlEncode(path)),
    response_type = "code",
    scope = "publish_stream"
};
var loginUrl = fb.GetLoginUrl(options);
```

Then this `loginUrl` value is added to my MVC ViewModel and used in a link in the View.

However, I've noticed that the `loginUrl` contains the `client_secret` value in clear text.  Isn't this a bad thing?  Shouldn't users *not* be able to see the `client_secret`?  Did I go about this the wrong way?

Comment: @CBroe: Yes, you were indeed correct.  Go ahead and add as an answer if you'd like.  I need to go find the tutorial from which I got that code and let the author know...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `fb.GetLoginUrl` method is rather simple, in that it just adds anything you give it inside the `options` object as parameters to the URL created.

So take

```
client_secret = "MY_APP_SECRET",
```

out of your `options` object, and it should not show up in the login URL any more.

Comment: In the interests of completeness (to help anybody who might stumble upon this later), this is the page where I got that code: http://www.thepcwizard.in/2013/02/working-with-facebook-c--sharp-sdk.html

Comment: @David Good catch with that. I blindly followed the developer's tutorial. I apologies for it. In order of further completeness, the article is now updated and fixed.